# WxPython[TextCtrl] : The way of locate the cursor to end of text using TextCtrl function.

Tags: python, cursor, wxpython, textctrl

nice to meet you. I have a some problem about using wxpython. That's I can't control cursor of TextCtrl Function. That is my wxpython code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
import wx

def get_main_screen_text():
    text = "\n       [Anyfusion Monitoring System]\n\n"
    return text

class Tom(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(400, 420))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        vbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)    
        self.message = get_main_screen_text()

        self.write = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, value=self.message)
        System_Checkup = wx.Button(panel, 1, label='System_Checkup')
        Open_the_Web = wx.Button(panel, 1, label=' Open_the_Web ') 
        Help_Desk = wx.Button(panel, 1, label=' Help_Desk ') 
        Exit = wx.Button(panel, 1, label=' Exit ')

        vbox1.Add(self.write, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM, 15)
        vbox2.Add(System_Checkup, 0, wx.TOP | wx.TOP  | wx.RIGHT, 15)
        vbox2.Add(Open_the_Web, 0, wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT, 15)
        vbox2.Add(Help_Desk, 0, wx.TOP, 230)
        vbox2.Add(Exit, 0, wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT, 15)        
        vbox.Add(vbox1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.Add(vbox2, 0, wx.TOP)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.EventHandler, id=1)
        panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Centre()

    def EventHandler(self, event):
        b=event.GetEventObject().GetLabel()
        if b.endswith('System_Checkup'):
            self.message = self.message+"\nABC"
            self.write.SetValue(self.message)
            self.write.SetEditable(False)
            self.write.SetScrollPos(wx.VERTICAL,0)
            self.write.SetInsertionPoint(0)
            self.write.Refresh()            

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = Tom(None, -1, 'Tom')
        frame.ShowModal()
        frame.Destroy()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I want to locate my cursor to end of text. But my program didn't work it. The capture of my wxpython program below.

[image]

Next capture is a expected result of wxpython program.
[image]

Thanks you so much. I want to solve this problem as soon as possible.. thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SetInsertionPointEnd`

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
import wx

def get_main_screen_text():
    text = "\n       [Anyfusion Monitoring System]\n\n"
    return text

class Tom(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(400, 420))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        vbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)    
        self.message = get_main_screen_text()

        self.write = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, value=self.message)
        System_Checkup = wx.Button(panel, 1, label='System_Checkup')
        Open_the_Web = wx.Button(panel, 1, label=' Open_the_Web ') 
        Help_Desk = wx.Button(panel, 1, label=' Help_Desk ') 
        Exit = wx.Button(panel, 1, label=' Exit ')

        vbox1.Add(self.write, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM, 15)
        vbox2.Add(System_Checkup, 0, wx.TOP | wx.TOP  | wx.RIGHT, 15)
        vbox2.Add(Open_the_Web, 0, wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT, 15)
        vbox2.Add(Help_Desk, 0, wx.TOP, 230)
        vbox2.Add(Exit, 0, wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT, 15)        
        vbox.Add(vbox1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.Add(vbox2, 0, wx.TOP)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.EventHandler, id=1)
        panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Centre()

    def EventHandler(self, event):
        b=event.GetEventObject().GetLabel()
        if b.endswith('System_Checkup'):
            self.message = self.message+"\nABC"
            self.write.SetValue(self.message)
            self.write.SetEditable(False)
            self.write.SetScrollPos(wx.VERTICAL,0)
            self.write.SetFocus()
            self.write.SetInsertionPointEnd() 
            self.write.Refresh()            

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = Tom(None, -1, 'Tom')
        frame.ShowModal()
        frame.Destroy()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks you. I'm solved a problem. every function is perfectly working.